# Runge-Kutta for PID and system in separate calculations without filter

Tags: python, numerics, runge-kutta

I need to calculate a closed-loop system in Python; specifically, obtain the PID response and then use the output to obtain the system response sample-by-sample with my own loop.

For this, I am using a fourth-order Runge-Kutta with an adaptitive step size to solve the state space representation. So far, the only way I managed to get a good aproximate response was by adding a low-pass filter with the PID:

In transfer function form, my PID without filter:

$$ G(s)_c = K_p + \displaystyle\frac{K_i}{s} + \displaystyle\frac{K_dN}{1+ \displaystyle\frac{N}{s}}$$

My PID with the filter:

$$ G(s)_c = \displaystyle\frac{1}{0.1s + 1}\left(K_p + \displaystyle\frac{K_i}{s} + \displaystyle\frac{K_dN}{1+ \displaystyle\frac{N}{s}}\right)$$

With an example system:

$$G(s) = \displaystyle\frac{1}{s^2 + s + 1}$$,

where $K_p = K_i = K_d = 1$ and $N = 100 $

Result with the filter:

[image]

and without the filter:

[image]

The expected response should resemble the first image, but the filter adds tiny changes to the response. If I calculate PID + system in one transfer function, I get the expected results and I don't need the filter (probably because the system act as a filter), but, like i said, the requirement is to make the calculation of the PID separately.

I can also obtain the expected response if I increase the relative tolerance and absolute tolerance of the RK4, but the amount of increase in the # of steps is unacceptable, from 890 to 4269. The system itself does not matter, could be anything.

Any ideas on how could I get an accurate result without the filter or a big increase in number of steps?

the complete python code:

```py
import numpy as np
import control as ctrl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import time


def norm(x):
    return np.linalg.norm(x) / x.size**0.5


def runge_kutta(ss, x, h, inputValue):
    k1 = h * (ss.A * x + ss.B * inputValue)
    k2 = h * (ss.A * (x + k1/2) + ss.B * inputValue)
    k3 = h * (ss.A * (x + k2/2) + ss.B * inputValue)
    k4 = h * (ss.A * (x+k3) + ss.B * inputValue)

    x = x + (1/6) * (k1 + k2*2 + k3*2 + k4)
    y = ss.C * x + ss.D * inputValue
    return y.item(), x


N = 100
kp = 1
ki = 1
kd = 1

pid = ctrl.tf2ss(
    ctrl.TransferFunction([1], [0.1, 1]) *
    ctrl.TransferFunction([N*kd + kp, N*kp + ki, N * ki], [1, N, 0]))

x_pidB = np.zeros_like(pid.B)
x_pidS = np.zeros_like(pid.B)

system = ctrl.tf2ss(ctrl.TransferFunction([1], [1, 1, 1]))
vstadosB = np.zeros_like(system.B)

min_step_decrease = 0.2
max_step_increase = 5
h_ant = 0.0001
rtol = 1e-3
atol = 1e-6
Time = 0
tbound = 30
sp = 1
output = [0]
Time_out = [0]
yb = 0
sf1 = 0.9
sc_t = [0]
start = time.time()
counter = 0

while Time < tbound:
    error = sp - yb
    while True:
        counter += 1
        if Time + h_ant >= tbound:
            h_ant = tbound - Time
            ypids, x_pidSn = runge_kutta(pid, x_pidS, h_ant, error)
        else:
            ypidb, x_pidBn = runge_kutta(pid, x_pidB, h_ant, error)
            ypids, x_pidSn = runge_kutta(pid, x_pidS, h_ant / 2, error)
            ypids, x_pidSn = runge_kutta(pid, x_pidSn, h_ant / 2, error)

            scale = atol + rtol * (np.abs(x_pidSn) + np.abs(x_pidBn)) / 2
            delta1 = np.abs(x_pidBn - x_pidSn)
            error_norm = norm(delta1 / scale)

            if error_norm == 0:
                h_est = h_ant * max_step_increase
            elif error_norm < 1:
                h_est = h_ant * min(max_step_increase,
                                    max(1, sf1 * error_norm**(-1 / (4+1))))
            else:
                h_ant = h_ant * max(min_step_decrease, sf1 * error_norm**(-1 / (4+1)))
                continue

        yb, vstadosB = runge_kutta(system, vstadosB, h_ant, ypids)
        break

    sc_t.append(ypids)
    output.append(yb)
    Time += h_ant
    Time_out.append(Time)

    h_ant = h_est
    x_pidB = x_pidSn
    x_pidS = x_pidSn

print(f'Number of calculations:{counter}')
print(f'Time:{time.time() - start:.3f}')

fig = plt.figure(212)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1.plot(Time_out, output, label='System response')
ax1.legend()
ax1.grid()

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax2.plot(Time_out, sc_t, 'r', label='Control signal')
ax2.legend()
ax2.grid()

plt.show()
```